# What is my login and password for command line?

Tags: command-line, nvidia, graphics, login, tty

Just recently got into Ubuntu and I am very unfamiliar with how this works. I was following some steps to install a GTX 750Ti driver and I couldn't get past the login when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Typing `whoami` on the terminal displays my login name yet when I type the exact text there and password, it doesn't work and says `Login Incorrect`.

Comment: The login and password are the ones defined during the installation. But you don't need and shouldn't do what you're doing. Just open Settings > Software & Updates (or Software Properties in some releases), find the "Additional Drivers" tab, select and apply the recommended driver version.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Which steps exactly are you following? The add the link to the instructions here, there may be a better alternative (see [MichaelBay's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976176/what-is-my-login-and-password-for-command-line#comment1566495_976176)).